# What happened to Python's rect class?

Tags: python, rect

On a Google Search, I found this article:

http://docs.python.org/release/1.4/lib/node201.html

Which showed examples of using the rect class, to perform union/intersections/checking if points are inside rect. Importing rect fails in Python 2.7. Is this class in another package?

Comment: that documentation is dated October 25, 1996

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume the question isn't really "*what happened to it?*", but "*where can I find a class like this that I can use?*".

Most GUI libraries have a class like this. For example: [wx.Rect](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Rect-class.html), [QRect](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qrect.html)/[QRectF](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qrectf.html), [gtk.gdk.Rectangle](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gdkrectangle.html), [PyGame rect](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect).

If you want a generic rectangle class without the overhead of a GUI library, I think your only option is [Sympy](http://sympy.org/), which has a [Geometry](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/geometry.html) module that may suit your needs.

Finally, you may just choose to roll your own. It's not very hard to make such a class.

Comment: Link doesn't work anymore. Try http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/geometry.html

Answer (score 3):

It's part of the Standard Windowing interface. To quote from the documentation you yourself linked to:

> Using STDWIN is not recommended for
>   new applications. It has never been
>   ported to Microsoft Windows or Windows
>   NT, and for X11 or the Macintosh it
>   lacks important functionality -- in
>   particular, it has no tools for the
>   construction of dialogs.

Answer (score 3):

The `stdwin` module containing `rect` class was obsolete since version 1.6 (see [these notes](http://www.python.org/download/releases/1.6/)) and I believe it was removed in some later version.

Answer (score 1):

I think the rest of the answers have covered you. However I was in your shoes, and made a generic module to benefit more people. You can find the project [here](https://github.com/Pithikos/python-rectangles). The module works with both negative and positive numbers on a screen coordinate system (y grows downwards of screen, x grows to the right).

Some methods supported:

- Distance from one rectangle to an other
- See if rectangles overlap on x, y or both axis (default)
- See if a point is inside a rectangle
- Align rectangles